# Let $B\subseteq S$ a non-empty subset, with max. Show that $B$ also has supremum and $sup(B)=max(B)$

Tags: real-analysis

I understand intuitively that if there is a maximum, then the supremum is equal to the maximum. But how do I go around and prove that the statement is true?

Comment: What is $S$?$ $$ $

Comment: What is the definition of $\sup$?

Comment: S is a set equipped with total order. And supremum is that the least upper bound exists.

Comment: Define $\sup$ formally.

Comment: $U_B=\{ s\in S|\forall b\in B,b\leq s\}$ The smallest element in $s\in U_B$ is $sup$

Comment: Define "the smallest element" formally.

Comment: If $b'\in B$ is the smallest element in $B$ then $b'\leq b,\forall b\in B$

Comment: It's straight from the definition of max.  (if such a number $s \in B$ and $a \le s$ for all $a \in B$ then $s$ is a maximum) and of sup.  (if there is a number such that $a \le t$ for all $a\in S$ but for any $u < t$ there will be sup $v\in B$ so that $u < v$).  Just apply those definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=\max(B)$, i.e. $m \in B \land [\forall b \in B:b \le m]$.

Let $U_B=\{s \in S \mid \forall b \in B: b \le s \}$. Let $u \in U_B$.

By the definition of $U_B$, we have $\forall b \in B: b \le u$.

We claim that $m \le u$, for if not, since $m \in B$, we have $\exists b \in B:b \not\le u$, which is equivalent to $\neg \forall b \in B: b \le u$, contradiction.

Therefore, $\forall u \in U_B: m \le u$.

Therefore, $m=\sup(B)$.

Comment: Note how trichotomy isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

Kenny Lau has already answered your question, and this one is essentially equivalent to his, absent the logical operators.

Put $s=\sup B$ and $m=\max B$. By definition, $b\leq s$ for every $b\in B$. Thus $m\leq s$, because $m\in B$. We want to prove that $m=s$. If not, then $m<s$, so there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $m+\varepsilon<s$. Since $m+\varepsilon$ is not the supremum of $B$ (it is smaller than $s$), there must be some element $b\in B$ such that $b>m+\varepsilon$, which contradicts the maximality of $m$.

Comment: Note how my answer doesn't use trichotomy :P

Comment: Noted; twice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two defining properties of supremum of $B$:

- No member of $B$ exceeds (is greater than) $\sup B$.
- Any member of $S$ which is less than $\sup B$ is exceeded by at least one member of $B$.

Let $m=\max B$. Then it is trivial that no member of $B$ exceeds $m$. And if $s\in S$ is such that $s<m$ then there is a member $m\in B$ which exceeds $s$ trivially. Hence $m=\sup B$.

As can be seen from above the statement you wish to prove is too trivial to demand a formal proof. The only reason it might seem complicated to someone is the way it is presented in terms of excessive symbols and jargon.